# In Angular 2 / Ionic 2 - how do I handle an api with server side pagination so the next page is loaded way ahead of time

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

An api exists with server side pagination. You send page number in your request and it returns the 20 records relevant for that page - with a total of 6,000 pages.
In my app a user rapidly clicks through hundreds of records and I’d like the user experience to be as smooth as possible.

If I wait until the user clicks on the last (20th) record from page 1 of results before requesting page 2 (and therefore the next 20 records) then there may be a delay as the data is returned.

Is there a recommended way to request pages ahead of time this way? Maybe some promise/observable/asynchronous magic?

Comment: Why not just load for example, 60 records or 3 pages in advance, than the page the user is actually on